# The wireless chipset's Wi-Fi frequency (Ghz or MHz) and Wi-Fi output (dbm) MacBook Pro 13' 2017 touch bar

Tags: wifi

I want to deliver my macbookpro to another country (Taiwain).
  And to do so, the country ask me to provide the wireless chipset's Wi-Fi frequency (Ghz or MHz) and output (dbm) information which is one of the input documents.

I searched in the Internet for half of day and I have known is that it use the "Broadcom 43XX" as the chipset and "Murata/Apple339S00056 Wi-Fi".

However there is still nothing about the  information I need.

And I had contact with the Apple Store and found out that they said it is the internal information they could not reach.

Hope here can find the information.
Thanks for watching this!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how much this answer will help, but unless I'm missing some finer details in your question, the Wi-Fi bands supported are 5GHz (IEEE 802.11ac natively) and 2.4GHz (via backwards compatibility with the 802.11n specifications).

**I'm not 100% certain** on the radio output power, but typically Apple hardware is rated at 20 dBm (nominal).

If it helps, all Apple hardware fully complies with IEEE specifications and meet the legal regulatory requirements for all regions to which they sell directly. And, just for the record, Apple does sell these models directly in [Taiwan](https://www.apple.com/tw/macbook-pro/specs/).

Also, by default Apple designs these products to ensure their devices

- do not exceed the level of allowable transmitter power, the different available channels, and the times those channels can be occupied.
- will **not** transmit at a power above what is allowable in any nation to which they sell, nor will their products use frequencies that are not permitted in any nation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your professional answer ! It's really helpful ! At your point , It really makes sense. By the way, about the radio output power , I "guess" the wireless chipset may be the same as the Apple AirPort Extreme.(BCM 43XX). And I found that it is 32.5 dBm which is shown by the apple website. I don't know if the 32.5 dBm could be the MacBook Pro 's radio output power !? But, for sure, it's safe to fill 20 dBm in the input document and also the frequency are 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz. – James yesterday   delete